# error parsing in php

Tags: php

```
<?php

/* User info to access to db */

$db_host = "";

$db_name = "";

$db_user = "root";

$db_pass = "root";

/* Create an object patient */

class patient
{
    public $name;
    public $surname;
    public $address;
    public $birth_place;
    public $province;
    public $birth_date;
    public $sex;
    public $case;

    public __construct($nm,$sur,$addr,$bp,$pr,$bd,$sx,$cs) <-- line 26
    {
        $this->name = $nm;
        $this->surname = $sur;
        $this->address = $addr;
        $this->birth_place = $bp;
        $this->province = $pr;
        $this->birth_date = $bd;
        $this->sex = $sx;
        $this->case = $cs;
    }

}
```

?>

I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE on line 26
```

why? where is the mistake?

Comment: public **function** __construct(.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `function` is missing:

```
public function __construct($nm,$sur,$addr,$bp,$pr,$bd,$sx,$cs) <-- line 26
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to declare __construct() as a function. Corrected:

```
 public function __construct($nm,$sur,$addr,$bp,$pr,$bd,$sx,$cs)
    {
        $this->name = $nm;
        $this->surname = $sur;
        $this->address = $addr;
        $this->birth_place = $bp;
        $this->province = $pr;
        $this->birth_date = $bd;
        $this->sex = $sx;
        $this->case = $cs;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Bad (missing function)
public __construct($nm,$sur,$addr,$bp,$pr,$bd,$sx,$cs)

// Good
public function __construct($nm,$sur,$addr,$bp,$pr,$bd,$sx,$cs)
```

Also, passing this many params into your constructor is not a good idea. I'd recommend implementing a factory, and passing in an array:

```
// Factory
public static function getPatient(array $array)
{
    $patient = new Patient();

    if (array_key_exists('name', $array) {
        $patient->setName($array['name']);
    }

    if (array_key_exists('surname', $array) {
        $patient->setSurname($array['surname']);
    }

    return $patient;
}

// Calling code looks something like
$patient = new Patient(
    array(
        'name' => $row['name'],
        'surname' => $row['surname']
    )
);

// Or you can simply hydrate the object after you execute your query
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $patient = new Patient();

    $patient->setName($row['name']);
    $patient->setSurname($row['surname']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`public __construct` must be `public function __construct`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
public function __construct(...
```

Comment: Shouldn't encourage him to drop scope resolution.